# How can I add an image without affecting the position of following divs

Tags: html, css

I have a class of divs that behave predicatively. The code is as follows:

```
.nav 
{
background-color: none;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: "comic sans", times, serif;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
margin-left: 2px;
padding-top: 15px;
}
```

This is inside a wrapper `id` navbar:

```
#navbar 
{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: #141414;
}
```

But whenever I try to add a picture or a large word to one of these divs, the rest of the divs, which contain text, are moved so that only the part containing the text is inside the wrapper and the rest hang down and outside of the wrapper.

For example:

```
<div id="navbar">

        <div class="nav" style="background-image:url('xyz.jpg'); width: 
100px; height: 50px;"></div>
        <div class="nav"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: 
none;">Home</a></div>
        <div class="nav"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: 
none;">Genres</a></div>
        <div class="nav"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: 
none;">Favorites</a></div>


    </div> <!-- End of navbar -->
```

I tried searching online but I have not been able to find a solution to this issue. Has anyone experienced this issue in the past?

Comment: try `#navbar { display: flex;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add: `{ display: flex;}`

```css
.nav 
{
background-color: none;
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: "comic sans", times, serif;
margin: auto;
margin-left: 2px;
padding-top: 15px;
} 
#navbar 
{
display:flex;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: #141414;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">

        <div class="nav" style="background-image:url('paper.gif'); width: 
100px; height: 50px;"></div>
        <div class="nav"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: 
none;">Home</a></div>
        <div class="nav"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: 
none;">Genres</a></div>
        <div class="nav"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: 
none;">Favorites</a></div>


    </div>
```

You can read about `flex` here:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Tell me if you need help

Comment: Thank you! It does help me. I was able to fix the layout because of you. I had been stuck on this issue for two days.

Comment: @JulianVelazquez I really appricate if you up vote and mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

add to .nav

```
     .nav{
         overflow:"hidden";
         }
```

also i recommend to use:

```
     <div class="nav">
         <img src="logo.png"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
     </div>
```

insted

```
      <div class="nav" style="background-image:url('logo.png'); width:
      100px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

also if you want to div to be 50px and its have 15px padding so acctually you want to set the height for 35px (35px height + 15px padding = 50px) so:

```
     .nav{
         height:35px;
         }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. The solution I came to did not involve flexbox after all. It uses your idea of filling the div with the image set to 100% both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring all child objects as inline-block and adjusting the line-height for the nav divs to the height of the nav divs themselves seems to have worked.

I managed to make it work with the following configuration:

```
        body
        {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #navbar 
        {
            /*shape*/
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;

            /*decoration*/
            background-color: #141414;

            /*display: no configuration needed*/
            /*Lesson learned - Only display methods applied to child objects count*/

        }

.nav 
        {
            /*decoration*/
            background-color: none;
            color: white;
            font-family: "comic sans", times, serif;
            overflow: hidden;
            line-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;

            /*shape*/
            height: 50px;

            /*display*/
            display: inline-block;
            margin: auto;
            margin-left: 2px;
        } 
        #navbar 
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #141414;
        }

        #logo 
        {
            /*decoration*/
            background-image: url("https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/rfr/logo_gmail_lockup_dark_1x.png");
            background-size: 100%;

            /*shape*/
            height: 50px;
            width: 200px;

            /*display*/
            display:inline-block;

        }
            <div id="navbar">

            <div id="logo"></div>
            <div class="nav"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Home</a></div>
            <div class="nav"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Genres</a></div>
            <div class="nav"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Favorites</a></div>
            

</div> <!-- End of navbar -->
```